# How to output elements with partly indent format optionally?

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

For example, in html "`div`" is uasully indent format, but the "`span`" in "`p`" is not. If "span" is indent format, the letters in different "`span`" will be separated with extra spaces in web browser. How can we ouput "`div`" with indent format. and "`span`" without? The elament name is dynamic and got by program code, like that:

```
<xsl:element name="{$var1}">
    ...
    <xsl:element name="{$var2}">
        ...
        <xsl:element name="{$var3}">...</xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
```

How to optionally make each element to be outputted with or without indent format ?

The minimal but complete example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="3.0">

<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="(1 to 3)">
                <xsl:element name="p">
                    <xsl:attribute name="style"/>
                    <xsl:text>para_</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    <xsl:element name="span">
                        <xsl:attribute name="style"/>
                        num_<xsl:value-of select="."/>,
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="span">
                        <xsl:attribute name="style"/>
                        position_<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>,
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>                
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

no need source document.

the output:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p style="">para_1<span style="">
            num_1,
        </span><span style="">
            position_1,
        </span></p>
        <p style="">para_2<span style="">
            num_2,
        </span><span style="">
            position_2,
        </span></p>
        <p style="">para_3<span style="">
            num_3,
        </span><span style="">
            position_3,
        </span></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

what I want is:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p style="">para_1<span style="">num_1,</span><span style="">position_1,</span></p>
        <p style="">para_2<span style="">num_2,</span><span style="">position_2,</span></p>
        <p style="">para_3<span style="">num_3,</span><span style="">position_3,</span></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give a minimal but complete example (input, XSLT, output you want, output you get)? Normally for text/html output and the `xsl:output` `method="html"` and non-namespace HTML elements or the output method `xhtml` for XHTML 1 namespaced HTML elements you should get formatting and indentation that "knows" and "applies" rules based on the definition of HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your example, you need to be careful, if you want to control white space inside of elements where you mix XSLT elements (like `xsl:value-of`) and plain text, then you might need to ensure you wrap all literal text as needed in `xsl:text` elements, see https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWBq which does

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="(1 to 3)">
                <xsl:element name="p">
                    <xsl:attribute name="style"/>
                    <xsl:text>para_</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    <xsl:element name="span">
                        <xsl:attribute name="style"/>
                        <xsl:text>num_</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="span">
                        <xsl:attribute name="style"/>
                        <xsl:text>position_</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>                
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

The white space you have experienced in your output and that you don't want is inserted in your XSLT code by writing e.g.

```
                <xsl:element name="span">
                    <xsl:attribute name="style"/>
                    num_<xsl:value-of select="."/>,
                </xsl:element>
```

that way the the comma `,` is trailed by a line break.

In general, for XSLT 3, if you use declare `<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>`, then, according to https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization-31/#HTML_INDENT, the XSLT processor during serialization when indenting, observes the following rules:

> 7.4.3 HTML Output Method: the indent and suppress-indentation Parameters If the indent parameter has one of the values yes, true or 1, then the HTML output method MAY add or remove whitespace as it serializes the result tree, if it observes the following constraints:
>
> - Whitespace MUST NOT be added other than before or after an element, or
>     adjacent to an existing whitespace character.
> - Whitespace MUST NOT be added or removed adjacent to an inline element.
>     The inline elements are those included in the %inline category of any
>     of the HTML 4.01 DTDs or those elements defined to be phrasing
>     elements in HTML5, as well as the ins and del elements if they are
>     used as inline elements (i.e., if they do not contain element
>     children).
> - Whitespace MUST NOT be added or removed inside a formatted element,
>     the formatted elements being pre, script, style, title, and textarea.
> - Whitespace characters MUST NOT be added in the content of an element
>     whose expanded QName matches a member of the list of expanded QNames
>     in the value of the suppress-indentation parameter. The expanded QName
>     of an element node is considered to match a member of the list of
>     expanded QNames if:
>
>   - the two expanded QNames are equal;
>   - the expanded QNames both have null namespace URIs, and the local parts
>       of the two QNames are equal without regard to case; or
>   - the value of the requested HTML version is 5.0, the local parts of the
>       two QNames are equal without regard to case and one QName has a null
>       namespace URI and the namespace URI of the other is equal to the XHTML
>       namespace URI.

That doesn't depend on using literal result elements or `xsl:element` to create your result elements, the right output method `html` together with no namespace for those result elements, enables the XSLT processor to serialize according to the rules of the used HTML version https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization-31/#HTML_VERSION.

Comment: I have test to add `indent="yes"` in "xsl:output" , but it still doesn't work . and your answer is hard to undertand for me, cause my poor english. Ok I'wll take some time to read it .

Comment: Would you like to give me an advise on my example. The result is just a text file, no relationship with version of html or web browser.

Comment: @cmf41013, see the edit, the problems you have encountered can be solved by using `xsl:text` to control exactly which literal text is created exactly.

Comment: You solved the example problem. but I find if setting the `xsl:output` method to 'xhtml' , the white  space will appear in you code. How to force spans in  one line with 'xhtml' method.  Forgive I'm so troublesome.

Comment: @cmf41013, consider to ask a new question with the necessary details (minimal samples of input, XSLT, result you want and the one you get) and an explanation as to why you need to use output method `xhtml`.

Comment: With output method XHTML, you can control which elements are indented using the suppress-indentation option on xsl:output.